# PyCaret - How to have similar output in Spyder as Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, spyder, pycaret

I am running setup and comparing functions of PyCaret in Spyder.
According to PyCaret documentation, there is always a grid as an output result.
I realized that documentation took for granted that code is running in Jyputer Notebook.

I am using Spyder as an IDE for Machine learning problem and I see that after running abovementioned functions, no results in output.

Is there any workaround in order to continue with Spyder?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I haven't used that library, but if it expects to run in a notebook, then probably won't show its output in Spyder. We're aware of this limitation for other libraries (such as Bokeh and Altair) and we plan to fix it in Spyder 5, to be released next year.

Answer (score 1):

By default it uses an HTML output optimized for iPython. To disable, when you call setup, set the "html" parameter to false. eg.

```
setup(data, 'target', html=False)
```

[image]

https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/classification.html#pycaret.classification.setup